# remote interaction with WPF C# desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, grails

I have created a standalone application with `WPF` and I need to use some of its functions via web.

In few words, **I would like that an user can access a web page and have the chance to insert some data and invoke some of the functions present in desktop application, which is running on a remote machine.**

> My idea is to create a `Grails` web appplication that interacts with my  `WPF` application, that is installed on the same machine.
>
> **What could be the right approach ?**

Is it possible to expose some of desktop application methods via `webservices` and invoke it from the web app? Or do I need to create a sort of API library and install both web app and desktop app in the same machine?
How can I create `webservices` or `API` for a `WPF C#` appplication?

Answer (score 1):

See [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx) (Windows Communication Foundation).  It can go both ways.  Host a web service on your web server.  Evoke a method on stand alone WPF application from a web page is not a common requirement.